# Why do I get an error on stack in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, stack

I have written the below code in Python but I am getting errors on the array 'stack' every time it says stack apart from the initial assignment. The error is "Instance of 'list' has no 'push' member".

To clarify, this piece of code is to run through each character and check if it is an opening bracket. It will push into stack, the opening bracket and I will match via an if/else statement to see if the they are matching pairs. If it does not match, return false.

Does anyone know why this code is giving errors on the stack? Stacks are very new to me and they are not making sense. This is the first piece of code I have written in Python so there may be an error in my syntax too.

I have taken the suggestion of the code from a video on stacks and tried to translate it into python to see it working. The code they were using was just a guideline of what should happen.

```
str = '()[(]())'
arr = ['(','[']
stack = []

for char in str:
    if char in arr:
        stack.push(char)  
    else:
        if stack.empty(): 
            top = stack.pop()
            break
        if(top == '[' and char != ']') or (top == '(' and char != ')'):
            break
return stack.empty()
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Note: Don't use `str` as variable name. You may confuse it with `str()`.

Comment: because there's no `push()` method on list. Use `append()` instead

Comment: There is no `push` and `empty` in list

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do. The ``list`` type has neither a ``push`` nor an ``empty`` method. Why do you think this should work? What do you think is ``top`` in the final ``if`` statement?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have updated the question. Good point about the Top. The tutorial suggests that this is the last node in the list. So I should maybe used a for loop with keys to get the last key.

Comment: I'm afraid the structure of your code does not make much sense. Leaving aside that many of these methods do not exist, what they imply does not fit together logically. For example, ``if stack.empty: top = stack.pop()`` means *if there is no element on the stack*, then *remove the top element on the stack*. Working through all of these does not seem suitable for the [SO] Q&A format. It may be more appropriate to discuss this in a chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function is not valid. List in python neither has `push()` nor does it have `empty()` method. You should modify you code to use `append()` and `len(stack)` instead of those two respectively.

The modified code would look like this -

```
str1 = '()[(]())'
str2 = '()[]()'
arr = ['(','[']


def check_parentheses(str):
    stack = []
    for char in str:
        if char in arr:
            stack.append(char)  
        else:
            # If our stack is empty, there's no closing bracket to match the opening one, hence invalid
            if not stack:        # Same as len(stack) == 0
                return "Invalid"
            else:
                # if closing bracket doesn't match opening bracket, then too it's invalid
                top = stack.pop()
                if(top=='[' and char != ']' or top == '(' and char != ')' ):
                    return "Invalid"
    # If all the above checks are passed, we can be sure that parentheses are valid and balanced :)
    return "Valid"


print(check_parentheses(str1))
print(check_parentheses(str2))
```

**Output :**

```
Invalid
Valid
```

I would suggest you to refer  [python docs - list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to get more information on lists and the methods that you can use on them.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is incredibly helpful for me to understand where I am going wrong in my translation. I've got a lot to learn on this. That explains why it was flagging "push".

Comment: Glad to help !  I have also included a link where you can learn about other methods used in list

Comment: Note that containers have boolean meaning – it is idiomatic to use ``if not stack:`` instead of ``if len(stack) == 0:``. Using strings to contain results is fragile; returning ``True`` or ``False`` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yea, right. But, I thought explicitly mentioning `len(stack)==0` would be more understandable. I have made the edit and included your suggestion